# No exit animation applied - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a `paper-icon-button` that animates (spin & opacity) when I hover an image using `on-mouseenter` and `on-mouseleave`.

The animations occur properly `on-mouseenter`, but the paper-icon-button simply disappears `on-mouseleave` rather than repeating the animation.

Can anybody help?

**HTML**

```
<img id="avatar" class="userAvatar" src="../images/hipster.png" slot="item-icon" on-mouseenter="cogSpin" on-mouseleave="cogSpin"></img> 
<paper-icon-button id="cogSpin" icon="settings" class="cog" on-click="doSomething"></paper-icon-button>
```

**CSS**

```
.cog {
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    top: 129px;
    left: 64px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s, transform ease-in-out 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.cogOn {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

**JS**

```
cogSpin : function() {
// css class only applied if the drawer containing it has been expanded
   if(this.$.drawer.classList.contains('drawerExpand')) {
       this.$.cogSpin.classList.toggle('cogOn');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `visibility:hidden;` and it's counterpart is not an animatable CSS property. (*[See dev docs regarding interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility#Interpolation)*)

Change your CSS rule to:

```
.cog {
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    top: 129px;
    left: 64px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s, transform ease-in-out 1s;
}

.cogOn {
    opacity: 1;
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

The `visibility` property is unnecessary in any case thanks to your use of `opacity`.

Comment: Makes sense. I added the visibility bit for something else I had it doing earlier but forgot to remove. Too early in the morning to catch something so obvious XD. Thanks Frits!

Comment: @physicsboy Yeah, I'm the same before my morning coffee! Glad I could help! Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: I had to wait a few minutes before it would let me :-P

Comment: :P didn't even think of that! Thanks :)